# Why OnItemClickLIstener Is Not Work for PullToRefreshLIstView?

Tags: android

I am Using following code:-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsfeed);
    setAllControlls();
     myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            AppConstants.MYPREF, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    userid = myPrefs.getString(AppConstants.USER_ID, "");

    if(checkInternet(NewFeeds.this))
    {
      new callNewsfeeddata().execute(userid);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(NewFeeds.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    objlistview.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if(checkInternet(NewFeeds.this))
            {
                new callNewsfeeddata().execute(userid);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(NewFeeds.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    objHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case AppConstants.UPDATE_ADDRESS:
                if (!((String) msg.obj).equals("0")) {
                    System.out.println("inside---" + objlocationvalue);
                    objlocationvalue = (String) msg.obj;
                } else {
                    objlocationvalue = "1";
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    objLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}


private void setAllControlls() {

    objlistview = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.newsfeedlistview);
    objlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {

            int pos1=pos-1;

            NewsFeedModle objnewsfeedmodle = objlist.get(pos);
            String type = objnewsfeedmodle.getType();
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("job"))
            {
                String postid = objnewsfeedmodle.getJobId();
                Intent objintent = new Intent(NewFeeds.this,ShowNewPostJobDetails.class);
                Bundle objbundle = new Bundle();
                objbundle.putString("postid", postid);
                objbundle.putString("from","newsfeed");
                objintent.putExtras(objbundle);
                startActivity(objintent);
            }
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("deals"))
            {
                String postid = objnewsfeedmodle.getDealid();
                Intent objintent = new Intent(NewFeeds.this,ShowNewFindDeal.class);
                Bundle objbundle = new Bundle();
                objbundle.putString("postid", postid);
                objbundle.putString("from","newsfeed");
                objintent.putExtras(objbundle);
                startActivity(objintent);
            }
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("stuff"))
            {
                String postid = objnewsfeedmodle.getStuffId();
                Intent objintent = new Intent(NewFeeds.this,ShowNewFindStuff.class);
                Bundle objbundle = new Bundle();
                objbundle.putString("postid", postid);
                objbundle.putString("from","newsfeed");
                objintent.putExtras(objbundle);
                startActivity(objintent);
            }

        }
    });
}

private class callNewsfeeddata extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, List<NewsFeedModle>> {
    ProgressDialog objprogress = new ProgressDialog(NewFeeds.this);
    AppRequestHandler objApprequest = new AppRequestHandler();

    List<NewsFeedModle> objresponce = new ArrayList<NewsFeedModle>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        objprogress.setMessage("Please Wait While Loading...");
        objprogress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<NewsFeedModle> doInBackground(String... params) {
        objresponce = objApprequest.newsFeedRequest(params[0]);
        return objresponce;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<NewsFeedModle> result) {
        if (objprogress.isShowing()) {
            objprogress.dismiss();
        }
        if(objlist!=null && objlist.size()!=0)
        {
            objlist.clear();    
        }
        String msgcount="";
        if (result != null) 
          {
            objlist=result;
            if(objlist.size()==0)
            {
                Log.i("check",""+objlist.size());
                Log.i("check22222",""+result.size());
            }
            if(objlist!=null && objlist.size()!=0)
            {
             msgcount = objlist.get(0).getMessagescount();  
            }
            TabActivity tab=(TabActivity) getParent();
            TextView tv=(TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.notificationmsg);
            tv.setText(msgcount);
            Editor objedit = myPrefs.edit();
            objedit.putString(AppConstants.MESSAGECOUNT, msgcount);
            objedit.commit();
            objnewsFeedAdapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(NewFeeds.this,objlist,(float)objlattvalue,(float)objlongvalue,objlocationvalue);
            objlistview.setAdapter(objnewsFeedAdapter);
            objnewsFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            objlistview.onRefreshComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

I have define OnItemClickLIstener inside setAllContrill method but it is not working.listView is unclickable anyone suggest me .I am using github pulltorefresh code .I unable to find out what is issue because in other places it is working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `

```
objlistview.getRefreshableView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener...)
```

Answer (score 2):

`getRefreshableView()` won't help, because `setOnItemClickListener()` in `PullToRefreshListView` is just a pass-through method:

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mRefreshableView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
}
```

I had the same problem, and it turned out that I had clickable element in item layout. After making this element non-clickable it began to work.